# Will I be able to activate my MSDN media Windows Home Server with an OEM license key?

Tags: license, windows-home-server, windows-activation, msdn

Can I go ahead and install a Windows Home Server using an MSDN iso (en_windows_home_server_installation_disc_x86_dvd_x14-24276.iso), and activate it later when my OEM box arrives (OEM sku as bought from Amazon, http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-OEM-Home-Server-WIN32/dp/B001E5Q8CO/) , or will I have to wait and use the media that ships with the license?

1. I know that you can not do his with the trial, but the MSDN iso is listed as "retail".
2. I do not wish to use the MSDN activation key for this install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, it works.

I did install from the MSDN iso. It informed me I had 30 days before requiring activation. I ran for 2 weeks without activation. Then my OEM license arrived and I activated the server with the OEM product key without any problem. No reinstall required.

Answer (score 0):

The OEM license will likely NOT activate the MSDN license. My experience has been that the keys from MSDN work fine, but other keys, especially OEM, "not so much"